# Design a sort algorithm with running time O(n lg d) running time

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Assume that we know in advance that each record in an unsorted array is at distance at most d << n from its position in the sorted array.  We would like to take advantage of this property. Assume that all n keys are distinct. For example:  Let the list be 3 8 18 2 7 20 24 15 22 30 40. It is not hard to see that for this unsorted list each record is at distance at most 3 from its position in the sorted array.

Design a sort that has O(n lg d) running time.

It is assignment question. Some hints will be useful.

Comment: Achieving `O(n*d)` is easy

Comment: On SO somewhere there is a dupe. You can search for it, but I cannot recall the name.

Comment: It doesn't work that way.  Try something, tell us why it didn't work and ask for improvements.  We're not going to complete your homework for you but we will help you get through errors and difficulties.

Comment: That was the first question of O(n*d). I already solved that.

Comment: How is this primarily opinion-based? "Needs minimal understanding" I would understand (but this is not your average "code for me" question), but "opinion-based"?

Comment: Namely, I don't know any such algorithm, and I have no idea how to show any prior research.

Comment: You can sort into pieces of length d in time O(n lg d).  How quickly can you merge these peices knowing that each element is either in the correct piece or an adjacent peice.

Comment: @deinst got it, thanks. An ordinary sort of d-length segments, then a two-way alternating merge.

Comment: @deinst perhaps this should be posted as  an answer? You deserve the credit

Comment: @pwny I have gone through all different sorts, but I couldn't come up with O(n.lg d) running time. So, I just needed some hints if some sort algorithm consider the number of inversions and gives n.lgd

Comment: @Jan I have no need of stack overflow whoopie points any more.  A careful answer is more work than I'm willing to put in.

Comment: @everyone, sorry to barge in just want some clarification on solution. So the solution is basically merge-sort but the leafs instead of being the smallest of length 1 it would be length d. That and the fact that the correct position for a element is either in that same node (i  - d) or its siblings(i + d) would cause the merge algo to be n*log(d). Is this right?

Comment: @user814628 If I understand your algorithm correctly, then it is correct and `O(n log d)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my tip for doing it (I'd post a full solution, but as you say, this is from an assignment):

You already know that an element is within `2d` of the correct index. How might you be able to scan through the array, but only looking through at most `2d` elements at once?

More specifically, suppose you just figured out the `i`th element by checking everything from index `i - d` to `i + d`. How might you use what you already know to figure out the `i+1`th element in `O(log d)` time?

Comment: so, a rolling min-heap?

Comment: ... except you can optimise "pop-min" and "push" into a single "replace-min" operation that might be faster in practice?

Comment: @Andrew don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if you find your question answered to your satisfaction

Comment: @JanDvorak Sure. Splitting the two into separate pieces is really only to make it easier for some to understand what the heck is going on; I'd certainly use something like a replace-min if I were actually coding this.